# Enable greek spellchecking

Tags: spell-checking, ubuntu

How can I enable greek language spellchecking in Emacs to be the default spellchecking language, and how can change spellchecking between greek and english language?  (My system is Ubuntu 14.04 64bit).

Comment: I believe that would depend on which spellchecking program you are using (aspell or hunspell?).

Comment: i think aspell. How can I find out?

Comment: See the value of `ispell-program-name` (you might need to `(require 'ispell)`, this variable isn't autoloaded). Also see this question, even though it deals with hunspell, the procedure should be somewhat similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86554/make-hunspell-work-with-emacs-and-german-language

Comment: **How do I change ispell private dictionary**:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27551890/2112489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Hunspell spellchecking program**

**First of all**, you should install hunspell and after that add Greek Dictionary

`sudo apt install hunspell`

Download and Add greek dictionary to Hunspell dictionaries' path

`cp el_GR.dic el_GR.aff /usr/share/hunspell`

Let's test Hunspell at terminal:
`hunspell -d el_GR`
and then mistype a greek word.

**Secondly**, it be required ispell and flycheck emacs' packages as also a bit configuration in init.el

Add greek and english dic to ispell local dictionary

```
(require 'ispell)
(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist '("greek-hunspell"
                                          "[[:alpha:]]"
                                          "[^[:alpha:]]"
                                          "[']"
                                          t
                                          ("-d" "el_GR"); Dictionary file name
                                          nil
                                          iso-8859-1))

(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist '("english-hunspell"
                                          "[[:alpha:]]"
                                          "[^[:alpha:]]"
                                          "[']"
                                          t
                                          ("-d" "en_US")
                                          nil
                                          iso-8859-1))

(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell"          ; Use hunspell to correct mistakes
  ispell-dictionary   "english-hunspell") ; Default dictionary to use
```

Define a function for switching dictionaries

```
(defun  fd-switch-dictionary()
"Switch greek and english dictionaries."
(interactive)
(let* ((dict ispell-current-dictionary)
     (new (if (string= dict "greek-hunspell") "english-hunspell"
               "greek-hunspell")))
(ispell-change-dictionary new)
(message "Switched dictionary from %s to %s" dict new)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'fd-switch-dictionary)
```

Open a text file in emacs use F8 to switch dictionary and then enable flyspell minor mode

`M-x flyspell-mode`

I hope it helps.